# Sci Kit Learn regression, value too large for dtype('float64') error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, data-science

I have some data that I am reading from a CSV file and attempting to fit a Bayes Ridge regression model but I am getting a `Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')` error... Any tips greatly appreciated

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/baselinekWh.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

df
```

I don't think there is any NaN data because I can scatter plot the data no problem with matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(df['OSAT'], df['kWh'], color='grey', marker='+')


plt.xlabel('OSAT')
plt.ylabel('kWh')
plt.title('kWh Model')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

A df.describe()` looks like this:

[image]

And when I try to fit the model I get an error... Any tips? I am trying to follow some steps from Sci Kit Learn website. Could it be the parameters that I am calling out being the problem? There is not a lot of Wisdom there yet ;)
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#bayesian-ridge-regression

```
from sklearn import linear_model

X = df[list(set(df.columns).difference(['kWh']))].values # X-> features
Y = df[['kWh']].values # Y -> target

reg = linear_model.BayesianRidge(alpha_1=1e-06, alpha_2=1e-06, compute_score=False, copy_X=True,
       fit_intercept=True, lambda_1=1e-06, lambda_2=1e-06, n_iter=300,
       normalize=False, tol=0.001, verbose=False)

reg.fit(X, Y)
```

Comment: Could you please check _NaN_ values: `df.isnull().sum().sum()`.

Comment: That outputs `94` what does that mean?? 94 NaNs??

Comment: Looks like, it is. You need have a look into the data - for instance `df[df['kWh'].isnull()]`. Or, for instance, remove all _NaN_ (`df_cleaned = df.dropna()`) and try fit the model.

Comment: I wonder if its something I am doing when I created the dataset where the NaNs are happening. Its all time series data (5-10 minute intervals) where I did a `df.join` to combine two CSV files of kWh & OSAT based on the index. Then a `df = df.fillna(method = 'bfill').fillna(method = 'bfill')` which I thought would get rid of any NaN or missing data points. Then a `df = df.resample('H').mean()`. Would that process do anything strange to create NaNs?

Comment: Would you know how I could remove all rows in my df that contain NaN? Important that it removes the entire row so the time series data still lines up appropriately..

Comment: `df = df.fillna(method = 'bfill').fillna(method = 'bfill')` seems, should works. You could to debug using code snippet `df.isnull().sum().sum()` between transformations steps.

Comment: `bfill` uses the next available valid observation and works backwards. Perhaps some of your series have a NaN at the very end, making it impossible for the `bfill` process to get a valid next observation? Also, you can pass a parameter to `.dropna()` that sets the number of NaN entries are required for it to actually drop the row. For instance `.dropna(how='any')` drops the row if there is even a single NaN. Or `.dropna(thresh=5)` will drop rows with 5 *or more* NaNs in the row.